# Compilation of Etherpad fails in an OpenVZ VE

Tags: ubuntu, memory, java, openvz

I’m almost giving up, this will be my last try: I try to compile Etherpad on my OpenVZ server. It’s running a Debian 5.0 as the host system, in the VE I’ve got Ubuntu 10.04. I installed Etherpad in this VE with the instructions from the official Ubuntu Wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Etherpad.

Everything runs fine until it comes to compilation. After calling bin/build.sh as described in the wiki the first steps are running fine. But then I’m running into a memory error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cp": java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
```

Well, I understand the error message but don’t see the cause. The command free tells me that there’s plenty memory left in this VE:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2415236    1140872    1274364          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:    1140872    1274364
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Beautiful. But even repeating the compilation process doesn’t bring me any further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Posting this as a comment since I don't really have a solution for you, only suggestions. First of all - problems like these are probably going to get more attention at the vendor's mailinglist/forum etc. Secondly, have you tried their APT package - or do you need to compile it?

Comment: I used the APT package but still have to compile it, yes. I will try posting this problem in their Google group.

Answer (score 0):

I would check OpenVZ's [/proc/bc/resources](http://wiki.openvz.org/BC_proc_entries) to see if there are any failcounts. I've seen Java installation scripts misreport the causes of problems. The "cp" command (called by Java) may be lacking some other resource.